# assigning the missing values in a more high-efficiency way

Tags: r

I'm a new user of Rstudio. I hope to assign all the 98,99 as missing value of some of the variables in the data. So I wrote the following codes. I'm wondering is there any high-efficiency way to assign the missing values?

```
CGSS <- read_dta("D:/R recording/cgss2017.dta")
head(CGSS$d13)
cgss <- dplyr::select(CGSS,"a2","a421","a422","a423","a424","a425","c52",
                      "a44","a45","a46","a47","a48","c6","a10","d131","d132",
                      "d133","d134","d135")
cgss$a421[cgss$a421==98|cgss$a421==99] <- NA
cgss$a422[cgss$a422==98|cgss$a422==99] <- NA
cgss$a423[cgss$a423==98|cgss$a423==99] <- NA
cgss$a424[cgss$a424==98|cgss$a424==99] <- NA
cgss$a425[cgss$a425==98|cgss$a425==99] <- NA
cgss$a44[cgss$a44==98|cgss$a44==99] <- NA
cgss$a45[cgss$a45==98|cgss$a45==99] <- NA
cgss$a46[cgss$a46==98|cgss$a46==99] <- NA
cgss$a47[cgss$a47==98|cgss$a47==99] <- NA
cgss$a48[cgss$a48==98|cgss$a48==99] <- NA
```

Comment: If someone can help me with this, I'd be really appreciated!

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible example, it would be really helpful.

Comment: You could increase your chances of getting an answer by posting the text output of `dput( head(cgss, 10)`

Answer (score 1):

In general you can identify missing values and convert them to `NA` when reading them in, but this may not be possible with this function. To set them to `NA` after reading in the data, try this more efficient indexing approach:

```
> set.seed(112)
> x <- data.frame(a = round(runif(10, 95, 100)), 
                  b = round(runif(10, 95, 100)))
> x
     a   b
1   97  96
2  100  97
3  100 100
4  100  98
5   96  98
6   96 100
7   95  98
8   99  98
9   96  99
10  97  97

> x[x == 98 | x == 99] <- NA

> x
     a   b
1   97  96
2  100  97
3  100 100
4  100  NA
5   96  NA
6   96 100
7   95  NA
8   NA  NA
9   96  NA
10  97  97
```

Does this do what you want?

With `read.table()` and similar functions, you could use `na.strings = 98:99`. readr functions have an `na` argument. I am not familiar with `read_dta()`, but it seems it doesn't have a similar argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
cgss %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~if_else(.x %in% c(98, 99), NA_real_, .x)))
```